# Zend Framework bin deployed or should be pre-installed

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I am new to PHP and want to develop PHP application using Zend framework 2. I want to know if Zend framework is bin deployable or it should be pre-installed on the server to deploy application. If it should be pre-installed then is there any PHP MVC framework that do not need pre-installation

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean by 'bin deployable' - ZF is PHP, it's not distributed in  binary form. Typically, Zend Framework 2 is installed using [composer](http://getcomposer.org/) within the application itself. It's not something you pre-install on the server.

Comment: Thanks this is what I want to know. From bin deployment you can understand I have a .net background :).